# Problem to run the application; showing some error message

Tags: java, android, setcontentview

```
2020-08-21 21:08:03.197 14771-14771/com.example.incomeandexpendituremanager E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.incomeandexpendituremanager, PID: 14771
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.incomeandexpendituremanager/com.example.incomeandexpendituremanager.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: ScrollView can host only one direct child
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2946)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: ScrollView can host only one direct child
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child
    at android.widget.ScrollView.addView(ScrollView.java:279)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:871)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:870)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:870)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:999)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:519)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
    at com.example.incomeandexpendituremanager.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:75)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7224)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7213)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2926)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

Here,
MainActivity.java:75 line is:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

everything were fine. but i added some lines of code in content_main.xml and i checked those line, there is no problem but still i am getting those error message.
So, where is the problem??
I searched a lot but couldn't find any problem :( :(

Comment: What changes did you make to the xml file? The error is telling you that you have a ScrollView with more than one direct child and that that's not allowed, and it also mentions a "binary xml file". I'd start looking at any mentions of ScrollView in the xml file you modified.

Comment: @JustAnotherDeveloper,
Thanks a lot.
problem solved .
Take love brother <3